# Include ngShow in select ngOptions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I populate a select using ng-options. In the value it gives a addon_id (from json data) and the name is addon_name. This works using the following code:

```
              <div ng-show="group.group_optiontype == 'single'">
                <select ng-model="foo1" ng-options="singleAddon.addon_name for singleAddon in group.addons track by singleAddon.addon_id" name="addon-val-single" class="form-control-wrapper col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                   <option value="" ng-hide="foo1">choose something</option>
                </select>
              </div>
```

but I also have a variable called addon_priceoption (wich can be 'free' or 'paid') and if its paid i want to show addon_price ... now how can i include this login into my code? i tried:

```
              <div ng-show="group.group_optiontype == 'single'">
                <select ng-model="foo1" ng-options="singleAddon.addon_name for singleAddon in group.addons track by singleAddon.addon_id" name="addon-val-single" class="form-control-wrapper col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                   <option value="" ng-hide="foo1">choose something<span ng-show="singleAddon.addon_priceoption == 'paid'">{{singleAddon.addon_price}}</span></option>
                </select>
              </div>
```

this does not work.... what is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function in your scope like following

```
$scope.formattedLabel = function(singleAddon){
  if(singleAddon.addon_proceoption =='paid'){
   return singleAddon.addon_name + singleAddon.addon_price;
  }else{
   return singleAddon.addon_name;
  }
};
```

And change ng-options to

```
ng-options="singleAddon.addon_name as formattedLabel(singleAddon) for singleAddon in group.addons track by singleAddon.addon_id"
```

You can also do this by using filters.